# PhantomJs specifying custom font (.ttf) location

Tags: phantomjs, truetype

We are using PhantomJs 2.1.1 on Unix server to convert HTML pages to PDF files. The font we want to use is a proprietary font, hence for UI we are sending the font file along with html content. However, due to some known issues ([Issue1](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13984), [Issue2](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13008)) PhatomJs does not work properly if the font is not being fetched locally.

By default Unix font are stored at `usr/share/fonts/`. However, we do not have access to this location, can I provide custom font file location directly to PhantomJs?